# Why not get notification to IOS physical server with rest api in FCM?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am able to send notification using FCM. To both "android" and "ios physical device". I do my submissions through the "Firebase Console". There is no problem here. When I send with a "json" request, I can receive notifications on the "android" side, but there is no response on the "ios physical device". I am sharing my json code below. I should point out that I'm posting via "postman".

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "cr5bpZ2BQoqTYKHm3UA4U7:APA91bGNu..."
  ],
  "priority": "high",
  "notification": {
    "topic": "weather",
    "title": "FCMasd",
    "body": "messagingsdf tutorial"
  },
  "data": {
    "msgId": "msg_12342"
  }
}
```

Comment: if it works for android, and doesn't work for only iOS device, it's just a device token problem.
I think your iOS device token is incorrect.
Please check it again

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it fully. When I send notification via "FCM Panel", both devices can receive notifications. The problem occurs when I post via "postman". Android gets notifications, iOS doesn't.

Comment: Yes, FCM panel will work, because it's a broadcase notification.
but postman needs you to input correct device token.

Comment: You have to get the device token in iOS code.

Comment: I am getting a token value from Flutter as below. Isn't this it? <code>final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
print('token '+fcmToken);</code>

Comment: Eventually current reason is the token value.

but I am sorry, I don't know flutter.
I can show swift code.

Comment: I want to see swift code.

Comment: Okay, oh.. by the way didn't you setup the dev certificate on firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to setup a certificate file that enables a remote notification on Firebase Settings.
2. and then you need to get a token value from Xcode.

If you need a code to get a token, I can provide it.

Comment: Yes, I need a code to get a token.

Comment: The problem was as you wrote in point 2. I was able to get the token value with "getToken" on the "flutter" side. I did the build first. Then I opened the project with Xcode and ran it with a physical device. I displayed the token value in the console, just like on the flutter side. When I made a request with this token value in Postman, I saw that the notification came to my device. Thank you for your support. Good coding.

Answer (score 0):

1.check notification certification
2.enable remote notification option in Xcode

Comment: When I send notification via "FCM Panel", both devices can receive notifications. The problem occurs when I post via "postman". Android gets notifications, iOS doesn't.

Comment: check firebase server key (that key shared your backend)